# Подключение анимированной кнопки к коду

Tags: javascript, css, css3

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>CSS3 Animated Search Box</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://icanbecreative.com/resources/images/favico.ico" />
        <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,800italic,400,300,600,700,800" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <meta property="og:url"           content="http://demo.icanbecreative.com/css3-animated-search-box/" />
        <meta property="og:type"          content="website" />
        <meta property="og:title"         content="CSS3 Animated Search Box" />
        <meta property="og:description"   content="Your description" />
        <meta property="og:image"         content="http://demo.icanbecreative.com/css3-animated-search-box/featured.jpg" />

        <style type="text/css">
            html,body {height: 100%;}
            body {padding: 0px; margin:0px; background:url(image.jpg) ; background-position: center; background-size: cover; background-attachment: fixed; background-repeat: no-repeat;}

            .search-wrapper {
                position: absolute;
                -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
                -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
                transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
                top:50%;
                left:50%;
            }
            .search-wrapper.active {}

            .search-wrapper .input-holder {
                overflow: hidden;
                height: 70px;
                background: rgba(255,255,255,0);
                border-radius:6px;
                position: relative;
                width:70px;
                -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
                -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
                transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
            }
            .search-wrapper.active .input-holder {
                border-radius: 50px;
                width:450px;
                background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
                -webkit-transition: all .5s cubic-bezier(0.000, 0.105, 0.035, 1.570);
                -moz-transition: all .5s cubic-bezier(0.000, 0.105, 0.035, 1.570);
                transition: all .5s cubic-bezier(0.000, 0.105, 0.035, 1.570);
            }

            .search-wrapper .input-holder .search-input {
                width:100%;
                height: 50px;
                padding:0px 70px 0 20px;
                opacity: 0;
                position: absolute;
                top:0px;
                left:0px;
                background: transparent;
                -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
                -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
                box-sizing: border-box;
                border:none;
                outline:none;
                font-family:"Open Sans", Arial, Verdana;
                font-size: 16px;
                font-weight: 400;
                line-height: 20px;
                color:#FFF;
                -webkit-transform: translate(0, 60px);
                -moz-transform: translate(0, 60px);
                transform: translate(0, 60px);
                -webkit-transition: all .3s cubic-bezier(0.000, 0.105, 0.035, 1.570);
                -moz-transition: all .3s cubic-bezier(0.000, 0.105, 0.035, 1.570);
                transition: all .3s cubic-bezier(0.000, 0.105, 0.035, 1.570);

                -webkit-transition-delay: 0.3s;
                -moz-transition-delay: 0.3s;
                transition-delay: 0.3s;
            }
            .search-wrapper.active .input-holder .search-input {
                opacity: 1;
                -webkit-transform: translate(0, 10px);
                -moz-transform: translate(0, 10px);
                transform: translate(0, 10px);
            }

            .search-wrapper .input-holder .search-icon {
                width:70px;
                height:70px;
                border:none;
                border-radius:6px;
                background: #FFF;
                padding:0px;
                outline:none;
                position: relative;
                z-index: 2;
                float:right;
                cursor: pointer;
                -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
                -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
                transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
            }
            .search-wrapper.active .input-holder .search-icon {
                width: 50px;
                height:50px;
                margin: 10px;
                border-radius: 30px;
            }
            .search-wrapper .input-holder .search-icon span {
                width:22px;
                height:22px;
                display: inline-block;
                vertical-align: middle;
                position:relative;
                -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
                -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
                transform: rotate(45deg);
                -webkit-transition: all .4s cubic-bezier(0.650, -0.600, 0.240, 1.650);
                -moz-transition: all .4s cubic-bezier(0.650, -0.600, 0.240, 1.650);
                transition: all .4s cubic-bezier(0.650, -0.600, 0.240, 1.650);

            }
            .search-wrapper.active .input-holder .search-icon span {
                -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
                -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
                transform: rotate(-45deg);
            }
            .search-wrapper .input-holder .search-icon span::before, .search-wrapper .input-holder .search-icon span::after {
                position: absolute;
                content:'';
            }
            .search-wrapper .input-holder .search-icon span::before {
                width: 4px;
                height: 11px;
                left: 9px;
                top: 18px;
                border-radius: 2px;
                background: #974BE0;
            }
            .search-wrapper .input-holder .search-icon span::after {
                width: 14px;
                height: 14px;
                left: 0px;
                top: 0px;
                border-radius: 16px;
                border: 4px solid #974BE0;
            }

            .search-wrapper .close {
                position: absolute;
                z-index: 1;
                top:24px;
                right:20px;
                width:25px;
                height:25px;
                cursor: pointer;
                -webkit-transform: rotate(-180deg);
                -moz-transform: rotate(-180deg);
                transform: rotate(-180deg);
                -webkit-transition: all .3s cubic-bezier(0.285, -0.450, 0.935, 0.110);
                -moz-transition: all .3s cubic-bezier(0.285, -0.450, 0.935, 0.110);
                transition: all .3s cubic-bezier(0.285, -0.450, 0.935, 0.110);
                -webkit-transition-delay: 0.2s;
                -moz-transition-delay: 0.2s;
                transition-delay: 0.2s;
            }
            .search-wrapper.active .close {
                right:-50px;
                -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
                -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
                transform: rotate(45deg);
                -webkit-transition: all .6s cubic-bezier(0.000, 0.105, 0.035, 1.570);
                -moz-transition: all .6s cubic-bezier(0.000, 0.105, 0.035, 1.570);
                transition: all .6s cubic-bezier(0.000, 0.105, 0.035, 1.570);
                -webkit-transition-delay: 0.5s;
                -moz-transition-delay: 0.5s;
                transition-delay: 0.5s;
            }
            .search-wrapper .close::before, .search-wrapper .close::after {
                position:absolute;
                content:'';
                background: #FFF;
                border-radius: 2px;
            }
            .search-wrapper .close::before {
                width: 5px;
                height: 25px;
                left: 10px;
                top: 0px;
            }
            .search-wrapper .close::after {
                width: 25px;
                height: 5px;
                left: 0px;
                top: 10px;
            }
            .search-wrapper .result-container {
                width: 100%;
                position: absolute;
                top:80px;
                left:0px;
                text-align: center;
                font-family: "Open Sans", Arial, Verdana;
                font-size: 14px;
                display:none;
                color:#B7B7B7;
            }


            @media screen and (max-width: 560px) {
                .search-wrapper.active .input-holder {width:200px;}
            }

        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function searchToggle(obj, evt){
            var container = $(obj).closest('.search-wrapper');

            if(!container.hasClass('active')){
                  container.addClass('active');
                  evt.preventDefault();
            }
            else if(container.hasClass('active') && $(obj).closest('.input-holder').length == 0){
                  container.removeClass('active');
                  // clear input
                  container.find('.search-input').val('');
                  // clear and hide result container when we press close
                  container.find('.result-container').fadeOut(100, function(){$(this).empty();});
            }
        }

        function submitFn(obj, evt){
            value = $(obj).find('.search-input').val().trim();

            _html = "Yup yup! Your search text sounds like this: ";
            if(!value.length){
                _html = "Yup yup! Add some text friend :D";
            }
            else{
                _html += "<b>" + value + "</b>";
            }

            $(obj).find('.result-container').html('<span>' + _html + '</span>');
            $(obj).find('.result-container').fadeIn(100);

            evt.preventDefault();
        }
  
  
        </script>

    </head>

    <body>
        <form onsubmit="submitFn(this, event);">
            <div class="search-wrapper">
                <div class="input-holder">
                    <input type="text" class="search-input" placeholder="Type to search" />
                    <button class="search-icon" onclick="searchToggle(this, event);"><span></span></button>
                </div>
                <span class="close" onclick="searchToggle(this, event);"></span>
                <div class="result-container">

                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>

</html>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Title of the document</title>
</head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<body>

<input type="text" id="serchQ" placeholder="search condition">
<br>Enter yout query<br>
<input type="radio" name="group1" onclick="switchCondition('musicArtist')" value="musicArtist" checked="">musicArtist<br>
<input type="radio" name="group1" onclick="switchCondition('musicTrack')" value="musicTrack">musicTrack<br>
<input type="radio" name="group1" onclick="switchCondition('album')" value="album">album <br>
<input type="radio" name="group1" onclick="switchCondition('song')" value="song">song<br>
<input onclick="getRecord()" value="Search" type="button">

<script>

var url = 'https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=';
var entity = 'musicArtist';


function getRecord() {

var q = $('#serchQ').val();

if(q !=null && q!= '')
{

var theUrl = url + q + '&entity=' + entity;
$.ajax({
url: theUrl,
method: "GET",
dataType: 'jsonp'
})

.done(function(data) {
    let message = "";
    if (data.resultCount) {
        data.results.forEach(function(artist) {
            message += "Имя: " + artist.artistName + "; Жанр: " + artist.primaryGenreName + "; Ссылка: " + artist.artistLinkUrl;

        });
    } else {
        message = "ничего не найдено";
    }
    alert(message);



}).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
});

}
else
{
alert('Need terme!');
}
}

function switchCondition(condition) {
if (condition != null && condition != '') {
entity = condition;
}
}
</script>

</body>

</script>
</html>
```

Такая проблема, есть код без стилей, хочу подключить к нему анимированную кнопку, но как подключаю перестает работать мой скрипт, я так понимаю проблема в скриптах, но нужна помощь как правильно их настроить.

Вот мой код

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Title of the document</title>
</head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<body>

<input type="text" id="serchQ" placeholder="search condition">
<br>Enter yout query<br>
<input type="radio" name="group1" onclick="switchCondition('musicArtist')"
value="musicArtist" checked="">musicArtist<br>

<input type="radio" name="group1" onclick="switchCondition('musicTrack')"
value="musicTrack">musicTrack<br>
<input type="radio" name="group1" onclick="switchCondition('album')" 
value="album">album <br>
<input type="radio" name="group1" onclick="switchCondition('song')" 
value="song">song<br>
<input onclick="getRecord()" value="Search" type="button">

<script>

var url = 'https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=';
var entity = 'musicArtist';


function getRecord() {

var q = $('#serchQ').val();

if(q !=null && q!= '')
{

var theUrl = url + q + '&entity=' + entity;
$.ajax({
url: theUrl,
method: "GET",
dataType: 'jsonp'
})

.done(function(data) {
let message = "";
if (data.resultCount) {
    data.results.forEach(function(artist) {
        message += "Имя: " + artist.artistName + "; Жанр: " + 
artist.primaryGenreName + "; Ссылка: " + artist.artistLinkUrl;

    });
} else {
    message = "ничего не найдено";
}
alert(message);



}).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
});

}
else
{
alert('Need terme!');
}
}

function switchCondition(condition) {
if (condition != null && condition != '') {
entity = condition;
}
}
</script>

</body>

</script>
</html>
```

А вот та самая кнопка

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>CSS3 Animated Search Box</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, 
    maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" 
 href="http://icanbecreative.com/resources/images/favico.ico" />
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?
<script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js">
</script>

    <meta property="og:url"           
content="http://demo.icanbecreative.com/css3-animated-search-box/" />
    <meta property="og:type"          content="website" />
    <meta property="og:title"         content="CSS3 Animated Search Box" />
    <meta property="og:description"   content="Your description" />
    <meta property="og:image"         
content="http://demo.icanbecreative.com/css3-animated-search-
box/featured.jpg" />

    <style type="text/css">
        html,body {height: 100%;}
        body {padding: 0px; margin:0px; background:url(image.jpg) ; 
background-position: center; background-size: cover; background-attachment: 
fixed; background-repeat: no-repeat;}

        .search-wrapper {
            position: absolute;
            -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            top:50%;
            left:50%;
        }
        .search-wrapper.active {}

        .search-wrapper .input-holder {
            overflow: hidden;
            height: 70px;
            background: rgba(255,255,255,0);
            border-radius:6px;
            position: relative;
            width:70px;
            -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
            -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
            transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
        }
        .search-wrapper.active .input-holder {
            border-radius: 50px;
            width:450px;
            background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
            -webkit-transition: all .5s cubic-bezier(0.000, 0.105, 0.035, 
1.570);
            -moz-transition: all .5s cubic-bezier(0.000, 0.105, 0.035, 
1.570);
            transition: all .5s cubic-bezier(0.000, 0.105, 0.035, 1.570);
        }

        .search-wrapper .input-holder .search-input {
            width:100%;
            height: 50px;
            padding:0px 70px 0 20px;
            opacity: 0;
            position: absolute;
            top:0px;
            left:0px;
            background: transparent;
            -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
            -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            border:none;
            outline:none;
            font-family:"Open Sans", Arial, Verdana;
            font-size: 16px;
            font-weight: 400;
            line-height: 20px;
            color:#FFF;
            -webkit-transform: translate(0, 60px);
            -moz-transform: translate(0, 60px);
            transform: translate(0, 60px);
            -webkit-transition: all .3s cubic-bezier(0.000, 0.105, 0.035, 
1.570);
            -moz-transition: all .3s cubic-bezier(0.000, 0.105, 0.035, 
1.570);
            transition: all .3s cubic-bezier(0.000, 0.105, 0.035, 1.570);

            -webkit-transition-delay: 0.3s;
            -moz-transition-delay: 0.3s;
            transition-delay: 0.3s;
        }
        .search-wrapper.active .input-holder .search-input {
            opacity: 1;
            -webkit-transform: translate(0, 10px);
            -moz-transform: translate(0, 10px);
            transform: translate(0, 10px);
        }

        .search-wrapper .input-holder .search-icon {
            width:70px;
            height:70px;
            border:none;
            border-radius:6px;
            background: #FFF;
            padding:0px;
            outline:none;
            position: relative;
            z-index: 2;
            float:right;
            cursor: pointer;
            -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
            -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
            transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
        }
        .search-wrapper.active .input-holder .search-icon {
            width: 50px;
            height:50px;
            margin: 10px;
            border-radius: 30px;
        }
        .search-wrapper .input-holder .search-icon span {
            width:22px;
            height:22px;
            display: inline-block;
            vertical-align: middle;
            position:relative;
            -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
            -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
            transform: rotate(45deg);
            -webkit-transition: all .4s cubic-bezier(0.650, -0.600, 0.240, 
1.650);
            -moz-transition: all .4s cubic-bezier(0.650, -0.600, 0.240, 
1.650);
            transition: all .4s cubic-bezier(0.650, -0.600, 0.240, 1.650);

        }
        .search-wrapper.active .input-holder .search-icon span {
            -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
            -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
            transform: rotate(-45deg);
        }
        .search-wrapper .input-holder .search-icon span::before, .search-
wrapper .input-holder .search-icon span::after {
            position: absolute;
            content:'';
        }
        .search-wrapper .input-holder .search-icon span::before {
            width: 4px;
            height: 11px;
            left: 9px;
            top: 18px;
            border-radius: 2px;
            background: #974BE0;
        }
        .search-wrapper .input-holder .search-icon span::after {
            width: 14px;
            height: 14px;
            left: 0px;
            top: 0px;
            border-radius: 16px;
            border: 4px solid #974BE0;
        }

        .search-wrapper .close {
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 1;
            top:24px;
            right:20px;
            width:25px;
            height:25px;
            cursor: pointer;
            -webkit-transform: rotate(-180deg);
            -moz-transform: rotate(-180deg);
            transform: rotate(-180deg);
            -webkit-transition: all .3s cubic-bezier(0.285, -0.450, 0.935, 
0.110);
            -moz-transition: all .3s cubic-bezier(0.285, -0.450, 0.935, 
0.110);
            transition: all .3s cubic-bezier(0.285, -0.450, 0.935, 0.110);
            -webkit-transition-delay: 0.2s;
            -moz-transition-delay: 0.2s;
            transition-delay: 0.2s;
        }
        .search-wrapper.active .close {
            right:-50px;
            -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
            -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
            transform: rotate(45deg);
            -webkit-transition: all .6s cubic-bezier(0.000, 0.105, 0.035, 
1.570);
            -moz-transition: all .6s cubic-bezier(0.000, 0.105, 0.035, 
1.570);
            transition: all .6s cubic-bezier(0.000, 0.105, 0.035, 1.570);
            -webkit-transition-delay: 0.5s;
            -moz-transition-delay: 0.5s;
            transition-delay: 0.5s;
        }
        .search-wrapper .close::before, .search-wrapper .close::after {
            position:absolute;
            content:'';
            background: #FFF;
            border-radius: 2px;
        }
        .search-wrapper .close::before {
            width: 5px;
            height: 25px;
            left: 10px;
            top: 0px;
        }
        .search-wrapper .close::after {
            width: 25px;
            height: 5px;
            left: 0px;
            top: 10px;
        }
        .search-wrapper .result-container {
            width: 100%;
            position: absolute;
            top:80px;
            left:0px;
            text-align: center;
            font-family: "Open Sans", Arial, Verdana;
            font-size: 14px;
            display:none;
            color:#B7B7B7;
        }


        @media screen and (max-width: 560px) {
            .search-wrapper.active .input-holder {width:200px;}
        }

    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function searchToggle(obj, evt){
        var container = $(obj).closest('.search-wrapper');

        if(!container.hasClass('active')){
              container.addClass('active');
              evt.preventDefault();
        }
        else if(container.hasClass('active') && $(obj).closest('.input-
holder').length == 0){
              container.removeClass('active');
              // clear input
              container.find('.search-input').val('');
              // clear and hide result container when we press close
              container.find('.result-container').fadeOut(100, function()
{$(this).empty();});
        }
    }

    function submitFn(obj, evt){
        value = $(obj).find('.search-input').val().trim();

        _html = "Yup yup! Your search text sounds like this: ";
        if(!value.length){
            _html = "Yup yup! Add some text friend :D";
        }
        else{
            _html += "<b>" + value + "</b>";
        }

        $(obj).find('.result-container').html('<span>' + _html + '</span>');
        $(obj).find('.result-container').fadeIn(100);

        evt.preventDefault();
    }


    </script>

</head>

<body>
    <form onsubmit="submitFn(this, event);">
        <div class="search-wrapper">
            <div class="input-holder">
                <input type="text" class="search-input" placeholder="Type to 
search" />
                <button class="search-icon" onclick="searchToggle(this, 
event);"><span></span></button>
            </div>
            <span class="close" onclick="searchToggle(this, event);"></span>
            <div class="result-container">

            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: сделайте запускаемый пример, либо тут либо в любой песочнице, пожалуйста

Comment: @nueq не подскажите как его тут сделать?

Comment: в редакторе вопроса есть кнопка - "Фрагмент кода на Javascript/HTML/CSS"

Comment: @nueq добавил и кнопку и мой код